# UIImage couldn't load some png picture

Tags: cocoa-touch

I Use the following code to load png image:

```
UIImage *imageBack1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bar1.png"];
UIImage *imageBack2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bar2.png"];
```

imageBack1 work right when imageBack2's value is nil, Bar1.png and Bar2.png are located at the same place,but why Bar2.png couldn't be load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact , the problem come from the png file,but not cocoa. Iphoto couldn't recognize it.